# sudo and su root broken

Tags: sudo, root, su

I cant seem to get either sudo to work or my root to work.
i thought it was related to me changing the default shells or forgetting the root password but i rest the root password and changed the default shells from the emergancy shell ass wel as rebuild the selinux tags.

then i applied chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo from recovery mode this also did not fix anything.

Below is an illustration of the problem.

```
~/scripts took 1m1s
❯ sudo reboot now
Failed to write reboot parameter file: Permission denied

~/scripts took 3s
❯ sudo ./houdini.sh
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied

~
❯ su root
Password:
This account is currently not available.

~/scripts took 8m35s
❯ sudo -u root ./houdini.sh

[root@fedora scripts]$ cd ..
bash: cd: ..: Permission denied
[root@fedora scripts]$ mount -o remount,rw /
mount: /: must be superuser to use mount.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


❯ grep ^root: /etc/passwd
grep: CGI: Is a directory
grep: Desktop: Is a directory
grep: dev: Is a directory
grep: Documents: Is a directory
grep: Downloads: Is a directory
grep: git: Is a directory
grep: houdini19.0: Is a directory
grep: houdini19.5: Is a directory
grep: Music: Is a directory
grep: omniverse:: Is a directory
grep: Omniverse: Is a directory
grep: output.txt: Permission denied
grep: Pictures: Is a directory
grep: Public: Is a directory
grep: scripts: Is a directory
grep: Templates: Is a directory
grep: tools: Is a directory
grep: Videos: Is a directory

❯ id root
uid=970(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)


❯ grep root: /etc/passwd
oot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
root:x:970:0:Super User:/root:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

currently this worries me

```
❯ sudo killall -u root

~
❯ sudo usermod -u 0 -o root
usermod: user root is currently used by process 100784
```

(the process shifts every time i rerun)

Comment: Run login and login as root

Comment: Not sure i understand.
    ~
    ❯ login

    ~ took 5s
    ❯ login root
I beleave it wont let me log in as root with the same password that works to sudo su and that i just changed to I`ll try again

Comment: Can you login as root user? `sudo su`

Comment: when i log in as root i cant open anny terminal or chrome or firefox and my gnome system updater gui tells me it doesn`t have acces.

But i can log in.

Comment: i can sudo -u root
But su doesnt work
and sudo works but root doesn`t have acces.

Comment: what does `id root` and `grep ^root: /etc/passwd` return?  It seems to me that there is an issue

Comment: I added output above

Comment: could it be the r missing here ?
oot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

root shows up as oot in htop

Comment: root id is 0. Your root account in passwd is fake root - ordinal user. I dont know why you do this thing. Correct root account and remove fake root account. What idiot do this thing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the username of the root account has been changed to `oot`.

This might be a result of a mistake in editing the `/etc/passwd` file without using `vipw` to safeguard it... but together with having UID 970 as a fake `root` account looks more like your system may have been hacked: this looks like it might be the work of an intruder that tries to ensure the legitimate owner won't be able to easily revoke intruder's access.

See this post in Information Security StackExchange: [How to deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/39232)

Comment: Could it be that setting 'rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh' in grub to reset my password could have made this change ?

Comment: This is just my personal pc and I don't have the budget to spoof my Mac address and firewall everything. I have been having suspicions someone keeps hacking me but it might just be paranoia

Comment: If you edited `/etc/passwd` after doing a `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh`, that might explain the `root -> oot` change, but the fact that a new user with UID 970 has been created and named `root` is harder to explain as an accident. You would have had to type that entire line. You might be using an easily bruteforceable/guessable password while having SSH logins from the internet enabled, or might have made some other basic security mistake.

Comment: if i you realy think i got hacked i fear its worse and someone has been deliberatly targetting me  acros multiple reinstalls OSes and public ip`s.  i fear spoofing my mac adress wont help at this point.

I reinstalled and added 
PermitRootLogin no
to my ssh config

thank all of you for your time and advice. i really apreciate it

Comment: More likely it was a mindless piece of malware on another hacked system, actively looking for vulnerable hosts to add into a botnet. Perhaps to mine bitcoins without paying for hardware and electricity, perhaps to use your system as part of a distributed attack against someone else, perhaps to send junk email. If you have your system accepting SSH connections from the internet, you should use really good passwords or disable password authentication altogether and use SSH keys instead. Might also install `fail2ban` to block connections from an IP after a number of consecutive auth failures.

Comment: If your system is not using IPv6 or WiFi, then your MAC address is visible only as far as the nearest router, and malware won't care about it. If a botnet malware finds an IP address that contains a vulnerable service, it will automatically attempt to hack it; if it finds a SSH service that seems to accept password authentication, it may mechanically try all possible short passwords for well-known user accounts like `root`. It's much more likely that you had a vulnerable unpatched service or an user account with an easily-guessable password accessible to the internet.